# Android Studio Corrupted Projects

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

I have been working on an Android Studio project, and it was working perfectly fine yesterday. When I opened the project today, there were many errors starting with Android Studio not being able to load settings from the .iml file. There are many errors because Android Studio "Can't resolve symbol 'Class'" for my main .java file, which has been replaced with the following (incomplete) code for some reason

```
<application>
  <component name="ActionsCollector">
    <counts>
      <entry action="$Delete" count="19" />
      <entry action="$Paste" count="24" />
      <entry action="$Redo" count="362" />
      <entry action="$SelectAll" count="36" />
      <entry action="$Undo" count="1310" />
      <entry action="Android.RunAndroidAvdManager" count="6" />
      <entry action="Android.RunAndroidSdkManager" count="4" />
      <entry action="Android.SyncProject" count="1" />
      <entry action="CloseProject" count="8" />
      <entry action="CommentByBlockComment" count="1" />
      <entry action="CommentByLineComment" count="46" />
      <entry action="CopyPaths" count="2" />
      <entry action="DialogOkAction Enter" count="39" />
      <entry action="EditorBackSpace" count="6010" />
      <entry action="EditorChooseLookupItem" count="572" />
      <entry action="EditorChooseLookupItemReplace" count="1" />
      <entry action="EditorCopy" count="315" />
      <entry action="EditorCut" count="53" />
      <entry action="EditorDelete" count="211" />
      <entry action="EditorDeleteLine" count="3" />
      <entry action="EditorDeleteToWordEnd" count="5" />
      <entry action="EditorD
```

I have tried a few things online such as deleting the .gradle and .idea folders and going to Invalidate Caches / Restart, but I have had no luck.

I opened a previous (fully functioning) project just to see if there were errors with it, and many files are replaced with the same sort of incomplete code above, along with every file that has not been replace with this code having everything past the first fifteen or so lines deleted as seen here

```
package com.mathiasstrohkirch.(my project name).(my class name);

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.mathi
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

When the problematic files for either project are opened using a different editor, they appear perfectly normal and unchanged from the previously working code.

Comment: Solution for latest android studio https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746941/5773037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to "invalide caches and restart" Android Studio ...
it might have crashed while writing these files.

if this does not work, try manually deleting the cache (in the project and your user's home directory).

version control can prevent such situations effectively (in case there is real corruption of source files).

Comment: Thank you! This did not end up solving the problem, and I tried a few other things, but I just ended up creating a new project and pasting all of my code in.