# All Activities and layouts got corrupted in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a projects since 3 months. Today most of my activities and xml files got corrupted. I have tried deleting workspace.iml file but it remains same.Local History in VCS is also empty. Is there any way to recover my code or solve this issue.
Note These files are same as previous if I open then in Notepad app/scrc/main/activity.java, but showing different in Android studio

Here what my code looks like now

```
<component name="libraryTable">  <library name="Gradle: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3">
<CLASSES>
  <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3.aar/fb2536827bf92d82ab72080a9863eb78/res" />
  <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3.aar/fb2536827bf92d82ab72080a9863eb78/jars/classes.jar!/" />
</CLASSES>
<JAVADOC />
<SOURCES />
```

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apkfeast.class11walkthrogh"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'        }  }}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.apkfeast.class11walkthrogh"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="true">
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    <activity android:name=".Hyderabad" />
    <activity android:name=".Mirpurkhas" />
    <activity android:name=".SelectBoard" />
    <activity android:name=".Quiz" />
    <activity android:name=".Notes" />
    <activity android:name=".fedral" />
    <activity android:name=".sukkur" />
    <activity android:name=".larkana" />
    <activity android:name=".aghakhan" />
    <activity android:name=".sarghoda" />
    <activity android:name=".Rawalpindi" />
    <activity android:name=".Faisalabad" />
    <activity android:name=".Multan" />
    <activity android:name=".Gujranwala" />
    <activity android:name=".lahore" />
    <activity android:name=".karachi" />
    <activity android:name=".sahiwal" />
    <activity android:name=".dgkhan" />
    <activity android:name=".peshawar" />
    <activity android:name=".bahawalpur" />
    <activity android:name=".balochistan" />
    <activity android:name=".hydchem" />
    <activity android:name=".hydphy" />
    <activity android:name=".hydbio" />
    <activity android:name=".hydeng" />
    <activity android:name=".hydisl" />
    <activity android:name=".hydurd" />
    <activity android:name=".hydmat" />
    <activity android:name=".hydpak" />
    <activity android:name=".hydviewdown" />
    <activity android:name=".mpkVD" />
    <activity android:name=".fedVD" />
    <activity android:name=".sukVD" />
    <activity android:name=".larVD" />
    <activity android:name=".sarVD" />
    <activity android:name=".rawVD" />
    <activity android:name=".faiVD" />
    <activity android:name=".mulVD" />
    <activity android:name=".gujVD" />
    <activity android:name=".lahVD" />
    <activity android:name=".khiVD" />
    <activity android:name=".sahVD" />
    <activity android:name=".dgkVD" />
    <activity android:name=".pesVD" />
    <activity android:name=".bahVD" />
    <activity android:name=".balVD" />
    <activity android:name=".result" />
    <activity android:name=".bioquiz" />
    <activity android:name=".chemquiz" />
    <activity android:name=".phyquiz" />
    <activity android:name=".full" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

## Solved

I have fixed it by deleting all the files in C:\Users\cc.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches.

Comment: Surely in 3 months you've made at least one backup?

Comment: Yes I have backup but its one month old backup and what if I restore with backup and filed get corrupt again :(

Comment: All files are same as previous if I open them in Notepad++ they are just corrupted in androidstudio. Ithing this is IDE related issue

Comment: I have fixed it by deleting all the files in C:\Users\cc\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches.

Comment: Okay, that's a good find

Comment: You saved my life! deleting all the files inside the android studio caches folder worked like magic

Comment: Still same issue in latest stable release of Android Studio as of today 10/2021.

Answer (score 29):

I also had the same problem this morning.
I thought this was due to migrating to AndroidX but
It was wrong. It may occur due to improper indexing and building for e.g. the indexing is force stopped. or due to some IDE issues.

**The isuue resolved by deleting gradle and .idea folder in project 
and clearing cache of Android Studio IDE by D:\Users\ABCD.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches.
And issue was resolved.**

> Note:- Please take Project Backups Daily.

Comment: Just deleting the "AndroidStudiox.x\system\caches" has been enough for me. I haven't had need to delete the other folders

Answer (score 26):

## Solution for Android studio Arctic Fox and Higher Versions

### Steps

- Exit `Android Studio`
- Delete `caches` folder from

  ```
  C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3 // For Arctic Fox
  ```
- Open `Android Studio` and your code has being Perfect

#### Check your Android studio version and Target that version folder at below location

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google`

**Note :** `AppData` folder is Hidden in Windows

Answer (score 19):

Erasing the cache of the Android studio will resolve the problem, for that you have to go to:

```
C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches
```

(On windows)

and on Mac:

```
~/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/caches
```

Delete all the files there and restart the Android studio.

Answer (score 4):

I solved that by

Close project you are working on

//This enables deleting all cache files
Close android studio

navigate to .AndroidStudio folder and then sytem then cache

delete the cache

Go to your project folder delete delete gradle and .idea folder

delete app.iml file too

import project dont open as exixting.

Boom you done.

Answer (score 3):

Delete **caches** folder of the android studio

Solutions for android studio 3.6 or below android studio 3.6

```
C:\Users\{user}\.AndroidStudio{version}\system\caches
```

And above android studio 3.6 or android studio arctic fox

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio{version}\cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Close android studio then delete the cache found in

```
C:\Users\**user**\.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches
```

Important not to modify a file before having deleted the android studio cache

If you modify a file you risk not being able to recover your old code

Answer (score 0):

Rename your project folder and delete .gradle and .idea file inside project folder

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue so i am copy the files from Project location which is corrupted. In my case, there is list of files corrupted due to module added in Login Activity

1. build.gradle (Project)
2. build.gradle (App-level)
3. AndroidManifest.xml
4. activity_login.xml
5. ActivityLogin

**Steps to solve the problem**

1. I have deleting **.iml** and **.idea** file then restart the Android Studio.
2. Paste the content from Project Location which is corrupted
3. Commenting the code in which module classes available
4. Run the application
5. If you are using git then rollback the changes in corrupted files as copy-paste process as done in Step-2

Above one process is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a project cache problem (if you see all files in Notepad, it will look fine. No file is corrupt.).

I have 100% working solution.

1. Close Android Studio
2. Copy project folder
3. Rename new project folder
4. Re-start Android Studio
5. File->New-> Import from new folder
6. Delete old folder.