# Problem with Android Studio 3.2.1, corrupted code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on Android Studio 3.2.1 and Kotlin plugin 1.3.10. Suddenly, I face this problem in all .kt files or in Layouts. Also the Manifest is showing something like rubbish code. Please check the attached photos.

What happened? How I can fix this problem?

[image: AndroidManifest.xml showing garbled file with a PNG header]

[image: XML Layout file]

I thinks something wrong happened to my Android Studio because I test another project and the same problem appears

[image: photo from another project]

Comment: It looks like you overwrote your `AndroidManifest.xml` file with a .png file of the same name. Are you able to restore it from version control?

Comment: Michael Dodd..Already I have backup when I restore backup ..the problem still appear

Comment: I'd guess there's also problem with your backup then. Is it only your `AndroidManifest.xml` file affected? I also see the `selector` element in what should be a layout file, I'm guessing that's ended up being overwritten from `res/drawable`?

Comment: Either way I'd seriously recommend looking into version control tools such as Git to avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: Michael Dodd..in third photo there logo appear like wifi in the top of layout

Comment: There has been questions about "corrupted" files in Android Studio lately and seems like the files are okay on the disk, but there's a problem in Android Studio. There's for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557902/android-studio-3-2-1-keeps-corrupting-java-files-on-weird-xml) and plenty more.

Comment: Markus Kauppinen..this is helpful but now I return back to old version Or updated to 3.3 RC(Beta)???

Comment: I haven't experienced the problem myself and am using "stable channel" versions myself. I'd look at the older questions and answers for hints on how to proceed. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1) mentions a solution, but there may be better ones.

Comment: I return to old version 3.1.4 ..it is Ok ..thanks  Markus Kauppinen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: Solution for latest android studio https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746941/5773037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know ,,this is late answer,but in fact the problem here 
**you can fix it by more than way**::

1. update android studio Version
2. return to older version
3. clear cache for your project then restart

Answer (score 0):

You just inflated a binary file into your text file `AndroidManifest.xml`. As @MichaelDodd pointed out: it seems to have been a PNG. Maybe you messed up a drag-n-drop or something.

Try to restore your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: shkschneider..Already I have backup when I restore backup ..the problem still appear

Comment: Then that is interresting! When does your AndroidManifest file change? During compilation? Gradle sync?