# my XML File change automatically contain another Tag

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3@jar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd/hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/ae7787a563e6a1b1f17fd4ac43be3a3c8830cfda/hamcrest-integration-1.3-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

my xml changed and contains following code automatically 
java file are also changed instead of C(class file ) they convert in to j file
i am unable to understand please help me i am not able to edit my xml file i am trying to find answer but i am not getting proper help

Comment: I didn't quite understand, but is it the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254611/java-and-xml-files-are-getting-replaced-with-some-bizzare-xml-files), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872016/problem-with-android-studio-3-2-1-corrupted-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)