# Android Studio 3.3 bug

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.3 and I've been working on projects using the IDE for the last week. I've noticed that a times the java files are corrupted and do not open correctly. See the image. 
What might be the issue considering version 3.3 has been released in the stable channel. [image]

Comment: Looks like encoding issue. The file is probably encoded in Widows-1252 but the editor tries to open it as UTF8. Try clicking "Reload as Windows-1252" Will that display correctly?

Comment: No it doesn't display correctly after clicking "Reload as Windows-1252"

Comment: Same problem as e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417394/android-studio-shows-xml-in-java-file-even-when-actual-file-has-java-code-only), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254611/java-and-xml-files-are-getting-replaced-with-some-bizzare-xml-files), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872016/problem-with-android-studio-3-2-1-corrupted-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1)? I haven't seen that myself, but there are some ideas under those questions.