# after running my app all the files code changes into invalid code

Tags: android, android-studio

i dont even know what to do now.
i just build the project ran the app. the all of sudden all xml files and java files into some invalid characters.

follow is one of my xml file

����   3 
     #status_bar_notification_info_maxnum I 
ConstantValue    ()V Code LineNumberTable LocalVariableTable this integer InnerClasses &Landroid/support/customview/R$integer; 
SourceFile R.java     $android/support/customview/R$integer java/lang/Object android/support/customview/R 1                       
   /     *� �           o

i reinstalled the android studio too.
i tried clean and build too.
nothing works.
please some one help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423372/android-studio-3-3-bug), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417394/corrupted-java-files-in-android-studio), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254611/java-and-xml-files-are-getting-replaced-with-some-bizzare-xml-files), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872016/problem-with-android-studio-3-2-1-corrupted-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1)? There are even more similar older questions. Have a look for ideas.

Comment: thank you so much, your answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1 with this solution