# Error AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm new to android app development with Android Studio and I came across this error when trying to run my app

> Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

I found out that my AndroidManifest.xml file had some weird characters in it

[image]

Can someone please help me out here.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow your AndroidManifest get corrupted. AndroidManifest should contain root application details and other project settings like as follows. Please try again
by creating new project.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: so i should create a new project and copy all existing file and code right?

Comment: Yes and don't forget to include all activity details in the AndroidManifest file.
For more details please refer android docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Answer (score 1):

Happy to hear that you start to develope app for Android.

And I suggest you can re-create a project, and the problem will disappear.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope this solution will help
2. this problem in your version of Android Studio
3. upgrade it to 3.3.RC3 and the problem will disappear

Comment: guidelines on how to upgrade it please :)

Comment: just download the new version and install it ,then open your project ,,all things will be fine ,,you can download from here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: also you can read this and follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872016/problem-with-android-studio-3-2-1-corrupted-code

Answer (score 0):

I read all the suggested answers below and mostly suggests that you create a new project because your manifest also looks very new.

It's very important to understand and memorise the body of the Android Manifest so in future you won't mess up again and can quickly debug your Manifest if some of the body went corrupted or accidentally deleted.

Comment: everytime i create a new project one of my xml files keep getting corrupt.. its either my colors.xml file or the ic_foreground.xml file.. could it be a kind of virus doing this

Comment: If this is a virus doings, why not do a test on different computer? Im not facing the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project from scratch is time-consuming..

I had the same error lately and
I solved this by clicking **Sync projects and gradle files**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all stuff but this resolve my issue:
When i open my AndroidManifest.xml file i release that doesn't contain the the code i wrote on it.so i write click the file go to show in explorer where i found my old code so copy paste and the problem resolved!!

Answer (score 0):

Guys If Nothing is working in your case like me then for protecting your hard work and your efforts You can do one thing very common but very helpful i.e.

1. Make a new Android Project
2. Go to android project Directory of your previous project.
   In my case- C:\Users\knegi\AndroidStudioProjects\Projectapp
3. Than go to main Directory inside your Previous project.
   In my case- C:\Users\knegi\AndroidStudioProjects\Projectapp\app\src\main
4. Copy all files from main Directory and paste them into main Directory of New Project.

Now all set open our new project and Run.